# undefined reference to `caml_names_of_builtin_cprim'

Tags: ocaml, undefined-reference

I'm trying to compile a tiny C program that uses the OCaml GC independently of Ocaml itself.

The code:

```c
#include <caml/mlvalues.h>
#include <caml/memory.h>

void foo(value v1, value v2, value v3)
{
    CAMLparam3 (v1, v2, v3);
    CAMLreturn0;
}
```

Compiling with:

```sh
gcc -L/usr/lib/ocaml -lcamlrun -lm -ldl -lcamlstr src/benchmarks/binarytrees-escaped.c
```

Output:

```
/usr/lib/ocaml/libcamlrun.a(startup.o): In function `caml_main':
(.text+0x62c): undefined reference to `caml_names_of_builtin_cprim'
/usr/lib/ocaml/libcamlrun.a(startup.o): In function `caml_main':
(.text+0x6b2): undefined reference to `caml_names_of_builtin_cprim'
/usr/lib/ocaml/libcamlrun.a(dynlink.o): In function `caml_build_primitive_table':
(.text+0x2aa): undefined reference to `caml_builtin_cprim'
/usr/lib/ocaml/libcamlrun.a(dynlink.o): In function `caml_build_primitive_table':
(.text+0x2ba): undefined reference to `caml_names_of_builtin_cprim'
/usr/lib/ocaml/libcamlrun.a(dynlink.o): In function `caml_build_primitive_table':
(.text+0x338): undefined reference to `caml_names_of_builtin_cprim'
/usr/lib/ocaml/libcamlrun.a(dynlink.o): In function `caml_build_primitive_table_builtin':
(.text+0x3ad): undefined reference to `caml_builtin_cprim'
/usr/lib/ocaml/libcamlrun.a(dynlink.o): In function `caml_build_primitive_table_builtin':
(.text+0x3cf): undefined reference to `caml_builtin_cprim'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea which library I'm missing? I've tried with all libs I could find on the system (not using or including opam):

```
/usr/lib/ocaml/libcamlrun.a
/usr/lib/ocaml/libcamlrun_pic.a
/usr/lib/ocaml/libcamlrun_shared.so
/usr/lib/ocaml/libcamlstr.a
```

The installed OCaml is:

```
$ which ocaml
/usr/bin/ocaml
$ ocaml -version
The OCaml toplevel, version 4.02.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by including a dummy object file from the OCaml compiler, needed to make the linked OCaml runtime work:

```
ocamlopt -output-obj -o test.o dummy.ml
cc src/benchmarks/binarytrees-escaped.c test.o -L`ocamlc -where` -lasmrun -lm -ldl
```

dummy.ml contains only `let i = 10` (but seems like it can be empty too).